# AWS CloudFormation pseudo parameters are incorrect locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, sam

I am working on AWS Serverless application using SAM. My *template.yaml* has this line for defining an S3 bucket name:

```
BucketName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-visit-attachments-${AWS::AccountID}
```

When I deploy to AWS using `sam deploy` the variables are substituted correctly.
But when I execute the lambda function locally, the resulting string is `local-visit-attachments-123456789012`. I can't find where the `local` and `123456789012` are coming from since I don't have them anywhere in the configs.

How can I make it so it uses the same values locally as when I deploy to AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sam local invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html) takes `--env-vars` parameter. You should be able to overwrite these default values by setting `AWS_REGION` and `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID`.

Comment: Thank you Marcin, that worked. I just wasn't sure about the variable format, but `AWS_REGION` and `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID` worked.